# Python try and except bug (probably)

Tags: python, try-catch

I've worked with little personal assistant project lately and now I'm facing this problem/bug and I can't get over it.

Here's part of my code:

```
    import os
import sys
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import random
from os import system

from src import commands
system("title Assistant")

actions = {
    "open":["pubg", "dota", "origins", "spotify", "dogs"],#"open":{["o"]:["pubg", "dota", "origins", "spotify", "dogs"]},
    "hue":["1"],
    "clear":"",
    "hiber":"",
    "shutdown":""
}

class MainClass:
    #
    logo1 = Fore.CYAN + """Not essential"""

    logo2 = Fore.CYAN + """Not essential"""

    errorcode = "Something went wrong :("

    def getCommand(self):
        cmd = input(Fore.MAGENTA + "Assistant > " + Fore.CYAN)
        print("cmd: " + cmd)
        self.checkCommand(cmd)

    def checkCommand(self, cmd):
        actions = commands.Commands().actions
        words = cmd.lower().split()
        print("Words: " + ' '.join(words))
        found = False

        ekasana = ""
        par = ""

        print("running if " + words[0] + str(words[0] == "q"))

#Here's the problem. After I imput 'clear', which clear's the screen and runs mainInterface(2.0, randomthing), this if does not work.
# Here's the output
# Not essentialv 2.0
#                By Dudecorn
# Assistant > q
# cmd: q
# Words: q
# running if qTrue
# self.errorcode
# clear
# ['clear']
# Assistant >

# Why is is that clear command staying there? I am so confused right now.
# Read line 68

        if words[0] == "q":
            quit()
            sys.exit()

        for word in words:
            word = ''.join(word)# Sorry about the mess
            print(word)
            # Check for action without parameters
            if word in actions and actions[word] == "" and found == False:
                try: # I'm pretty sure that this part of code is causing the problem
                    # If you remove try and except, and leave just lines 70 and 71, code works as line 58 if statement's value is true.
                    # This is in the another file -> getattr(commands.Commands, word)(self)
                    self.mainInterface(2.0, random.randint(1, 2))
                    break
                except:
                    print("self.errorcode")
                    print(word)
                    print(words)
            # Check for action that has parameters
            elif word in actions and not actions[word] == "" and found == False:
                ekasana = word
                found = True
            # Check for parameters
            elif not ekasana == "" and found == True:
                for n in actions[ekasana]:
                    if n == word:
                        par = word
                        try:
                             getattr(commands.Commands, ekasana)(self, par)
                        except:
                            print(self.errorcode)
            else:
                print("Command not found")
        self.getCommand()


    def mainInterface(self, v, logo):
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        if logo == 1:
            print(self.logo1+"v "+str(v)+"\n                                       By Dudecorn")
        else:
            print(self.logo2+"v "+str(v)+"\n               By Dudecorn")
        self.getCommand()
```

And here's the main file

```
import test
import random


def main():
    m = test.MainClass()
    m.mainInterface(2.0, random.randint(1,2))

main()
```

So, when you run the code and first input 'clear' and then q the if statement won't execute. And I wonder why. I also noticed that if you remove try and except from first if statement after loop the code works perfectly. I could remove them but it wouldn't answer my question, why isn't the code working. Also removing try and except from the file should not have any effect on how the first if statement executes, as it comes up later in the code.

Sorry about bad english as it isn't my main language, and thank you for your answers. Also I want to apologize for that huge mess in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the answer that you are looking for, but it may be useful to check.

From the code below,

```
def main():
    m = test.MainClass()
    m.mainInterface(2.0, random.randint(1,2))
main()
```

, I see that by running `main()`, you also run the `m.mainInterface` function.

Now..you may want to check this :

The **method `mainInterface`** will eventually call the method `getCommand`, which will eventually call `checkCommand`, which..will encounter the `try` block in the `for word in actions` loop, and inside this `try` block..there is a calling of **`mainInterface` again**..so this process will be keep repeating.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You were right.

In fact executing clear ran mainInterface once more and because of that there was multiple getCommands fired when running clear. But I'm still confused, because removing try and except fixed the issue too. Why is that?

Comment: @Guy is your code now working? Like i said, because there is a `mainInterface` method is in `try: ...`, if you remove the `try` and `except` you also remove the method, which means stopping the unwanted circular process.

Comment: My code is now working. By removing try I meant running mainInterface method **outside** the try and except like this:

if something:
  #try
  method()
  #except
  #something